# Find some n such that $|s-s_n|< 10^{-3}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$. Let $s_n$ be the $n$th of the series and $s$ be the sum of the series. Find some $n$ such that$$|s-s_n|< 10^{-3}$$

Can someone please explain how to go about solving this question? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the elementary identity $\dfrac{1}{n^2} < \dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}$ for $n \ge 2$ to make the estimate  $$s - s_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac 1{k^2} < \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k-1)}.$$
Since $$\frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}$$ you have
$$ \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \left[ \frac 1{k-1} - \frac 1{k} \right] = \frac 1n$$ since the series telescopes. Thus $$0 < s-s_n < \frac 1n$$ for all $n$. Just take $n = 10^{3}$.

Comment: If 1 in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ is replaced with $(-1)^n$ with the rest of the conditions staying the same, how will the method be different from this one?

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is converging since:
$$0\leq \frac{1}{n^2}\leq \frac{1}{n-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{n^2-\frac{1}{4}}\tag{1} $$
gives:
$$ 0\leq \sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \sum_{n\geq N}\left(\frac{1}{n-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}}\right) = \frac{1}{N-\frac{1}{2}}\tag{2}$$
so:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^{1000}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n\geq 1001}\frac{1}{n^2}\leq\frac{1}{1000+\frac{1}{2}}\tag{3} $$
gives that the $1000$th partial sum is an accurate enough estimation for the value of the series.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\dfrac1n = \int_n^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{x^2} = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{dx}{x^2} > \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{dx}{(k+1)^2} = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(k+1)^2} = s-s_n$$
Hence, we have
$$s-s_n < \dfrac1n$$
This can be used to dictate the choice of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $s > s_N$ for any natural number $N$. Then, we need to choose $N$ such that $$s - s_N < 1/1000.$$ We know that $$s =\frac {\pi^2} {6} \qquad \text{and} \qquad s_N = \frac {\pi^2} {6} - \frac {1} {N} + O \left(\frac {1} {N^2}\right).$$ So, $$s - s_N = \frac {1} {N} + O \left(\frac {1} {N^2}\right) < \frac {1} {1000}.$$ Then, I think, $N \geqslant 1001$ will do.